# Laravel can't confirm delete with SweetAlert

Tags: jquery, laravel, sweetalert

I have this problem with Sweetalert - I have the following code but the confirm modal is useless, as the request pass it and user don't even have time to decide. I have to figure it out to stop request executing and waits for user decision (Ok/Cancel).

Here's the code:

```
<a href="{{route('notes.destroy', $note->id)}}" 
data-id="{{$note->id}}" onclick="confirmDelete('{{$note->id}}')" type="submit">
<span class="badge badge-danger">Delete</span></a>
```

and here's the jQuery (which I think it's the problem):

```
<script>
function confirmDelete(item_id) {
    swal({ 
        title: "Are you sure?",
        text: "Once deleted, you will not be able to recover it!",
        icon: "warning",
        buttons: true,
        dangerMode: true,
    })
    .then((willDelete) => {
        if (willDelete) {
            $('#' + item_id).submit();
        } else {
            swal("Cancelled Successfully");
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In blade file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/7.33.1/sweetalert2.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/7.33.1/sweetalert2.js"></script>

<form id="delete_from_{{$note->id}}" method="POST" action="{{ route('post.destroy', $note->id) }}">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    {{ method_field('DELETE') }}

    <div class="form-group">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-id="{{$note->id}}" class="_delete_data">
            <span class="badge badge-danger">Delete</span>
        </a>                    
    </div>
</form>
```

js code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('._delete_data').click(function(e){
            var data_id = $(this).attr('data-id');
            Swal.fire({
                title: 'Are you sure?',
                text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
                type: 'warning',
                showCancelButton: true,
                confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
                cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
                confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!'
            }).then((result) => {

                if (result.value) {
                    $(document).find('#delete_from_'+data_id).submit();
                }
            })
        });
    });            
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question correctly, you mean the sweetalert modal didnt provide you with any option on whether to continue or abort the decision after onclick event. try to add "showCancelButton" and "confirmButtonText" as below and see if it makes any difference.

```
swal({
    title: "Are you sure?",
    text: "Once deleted, you will not be able to recover it!",
    icon: "warning",
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonText: 'ok'
}).then((willDelete) => {
    if (willDelete) {
        $('#' + item_id).submit();
    } else {
        swal("Cancelled Successfully");
    }
});
```

Comment: No, the problem was this: ```<a href="{{route('notes.destroy', $note->id)}}" ``` as on click, it would already send the request for delete the entry BEFORE the user accepts or cancels in the modal. I removed the route and place a ```<a href="#">```, but now I need to map the cancel and ok button to ajax call. Any ideas?

Comment: @Cicharito what about you include the route redirect in  if(willDelete){ } condition?  that way, the modal will always triggered first, then only proceed to next action based on your choice of action on sweetalert modal

Answer (score 0):

Prevent the form from submitting using `preventDefault()`

```js
function confirmDelete(event,item_id) {
event.preventDefault();
    swal({ 
        title: "Are you sure?",
        text: "Once deleted, you will not be able to recover it!",
        icon: "warning",
        buttons: true,
        dangerMode: true,
    })
    .then((willDelete) => {
        if (willDelete) {
            $('#' + item_id).submit();
        } else {
            swal("Cancelled Successfully");
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<a href="{{route('notes.destroy', $note->id)}}" 
data-id="{{$note->id}}" onclick="confirmDelete(event,'{{$note->id}}')" type="submit">
<span class="badge badge-danger">Delete</span></a>
and here's the jQuery (which I think it's the problem):
```

Comment: strange, this should work, did you add the event param to your function?